# Are there any good texts on EEG analysis geared towards programmers

Tags: matlab, wavelet, eeg

I just have a quick question. I'm a second year computer science major with a background in C# and C++. I'm interested in studying neuroscience after graduation, and I've been researching some subjects on my own in my free time. I'm thinking of purchasing a Neurobit Optima 4 and writing some applications for it (specifically I want to convert unspoken speech into commands an application can understand and execute), but while I'm still in the research stage, I was wondering if anyone knows about any text books or websites that discuss the analysis of EEG data or cover topics such as Discrete Wavelet Transforms that offer programming examples?

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help

Answer (score 2):

Your application is not something that can be done very easily. The project would be well-suited for a PhD topic to be done over 4-5 years.

If you really want to work towards it, learn

1) Signal processing. Knowing just one technique (like the DWT) will not get you anywhere. Get a *thick* book on the basics.

2) Machine learning (supervised and unsupervised). Your application will need classifiers.

3) Basics of EEG. Again, get a thick book. Focus on continuous-data analysis.

4) Start reading publications in your field. Try sciencedirect.com, ieeexplore.org, google scholar, etc.

5) Offer to work as a research/teaching assistant with neuroscientists at your local university.

Comment: Hey list, thanks for the tips. One book Ive ordered is Bioelectrical Signal Processing in Cardiac and Neurological Applications (http://www.amazon.com/Bioelectrical-Processing-Neurological-Applications-Engineering/dp/0124375529/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1374081051&sr=8-1&keywords=Bioelectrical+Signal+Processing+in+Cardiac+and+Neurological+Applications) and I'm also looking into maybe getting  EEG Signal Processing (http://www.amazon.com/EEG-Signal-Processing-Saeid-Sanei/dp/0470025816/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1374080982&sr=8-1&keywords=eeg+signal+processing). Are there any others that you'd recomend

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment yet due to insufficient privileges, but I highly recommend studying time series in general. EEG signals are at their core, time series. IMHO, the 'authority' on time series analysis and processing is [Prof. Eamonn Keogh](http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/). If you check the 'my tutorials' link on his page, you'll be able to download an **excellent** tutorial on time series as well, to get you quickly started.

EDIT: I would refrain from purchasing a ton of books all at once.
Also check http://cnx.org/ , you'll find a lot of free courseware-materials or even books, written by reputable professors